# Javascript Error DOM Exception 11

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

Trying to implement Kolorpicker on JQuery 1.6.1 (Tried 1.5.1 as well)

http://code.google.com/p/kolorpicker/downloads/list

See the trace below:

```
Uncaught Error: INVALID_STATE_ERR: DOM Exception 11
f.extend.cleanjquery-1.6.1.min.js:18
f.buildFragmentjquery-1.6.1.min.js:17
f.fn.extend.domManipjquery-1.6.1.min.js:17
f.fn.extend.appendjquery-1.6.1.min.js:17
f.fn.extend.htmljquery-1.6.1.min.js:17
displayPickerjquery.kolorpicker.js:87
$.live.checkjquery.kolorpicker.js:118
Njquery-1.6.1.min.js:16
f.event.handlejquery-1.6.1.min.js:17
f.event.add.k.i.handle.k
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What browser did that come from?

Comment: I am the author of this module. I'd need much much more context to understand what's going wrong. This project is now located on github here: https://github.com/kamelkev/kolorpicker